# Route Add not taking effect Windows Server 2012

Tags: networking, routing, gateway, netstat

I'm trying to route traffic to a specific subnet through a specific device. I've added the route successfully, yet any time I run a trace route to an IP on that subnet, it is not routing through the gateway I specified.

I am trying to route all traffic from 10.10.18.0 subnet through gateway 10.225.178.41

Here's the route print:

```
    Interface List
    12...00 50 56 aa 3f f9 ......Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
    1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
    13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
    ===========================================================================

    IPv4 Route Table
    ===========================================================================
   Active Routes:
    Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface      Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.225.164.1    10.225.164.21    266
       10.10.18.0    255.255.254.0    10.225.178.41    10.225.164.21     11
     10.225.164.0    255.255.254.0         On-link     10.225.164.21    266
    10.225.164.21  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.225.164.21    266
   10.225.165.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.225.164.21    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.225.164.21    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.225.164.21    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.225.164.1       1
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     10.225.164.1  Default
       10.10.18.0    255.255.254.0    10.225.178.41       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    266 fe80::ccb3:38cc:49f5:6b39/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
    ===========================================================================
     Persistent Routes:
      None
```

Results from the tracert:

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert 10.10.18.254

Tracing route to 10.10.18.254 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1     4 ms     2 ms     4 ms  10.225.164.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.225.191.1
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  152.185.41.177
  4    85 ms    85 ms    85 ms  152.162.45.121
  5    85 ms  ^C
```

As you can see it is still routing traffic through the first gateway. I've tried setting the metrics manually so that default gateway was below the one I am trying to route through and it still didn't work. I'm stumped.

Appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

10.225.178.41 isn't in the same subnet as your machine, so it can't be used as a route to the destination, and so the traffic has to go to the Default Gateway.